# 401 Unauthorized Error when calling Laravel Api call

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5, unauthorized

I'm working on Laravel RestFull Api, where this Api will consume by same application. And Homestead environment setup on my Windows Pc. When I call Api by using axios, I'm getting 401( Unauthorized )error code. Can anyone please tell me why is that and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide some code what you tried? Somewhere you have authorization on your api and you doesn't send token or something through your header...

Comment: What are you using for authentication? Passport? If you are using it you will need some `client token`. And can you provide code for one request?

Comment: <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> in my Html Header.
In kernel.php:
            \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
            'api' => [
                'throttle:60,1',
                'bindings',
                'auth:api',
            ],
in bootstarp:
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
In Vue : axios.post('/api/customer/save_customer', form)

Comment: Ok. So first when you want to get your api you need to hit `/login` route with your login parameters. What are you using for testing api, postman?

Comment: For testing using web Browser( Firefox and chrome )

Comment: How are you logging in to your application?

Comment: Doing simple Loging of Laravel.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution, the problem was in Laravel Version. In my development environment the Laravel Version was 5.6.0 but when I set up my project in production it turned to version Laravel 5.6.39 due to composer update. So, due to version changes we got 401 Unauthorized Error when calling Laravel Api call. Now I just backed to Laravel Version 5.6.0 and everything working fine. Thanks.

Comment: This would not be the reason why.  From 5.6.0 to 5.6.39 there would be no immediate breaks that would cause it.